# How to convert a list of indexes into a binary number?

Tags: python, list, binary

I have a list of numbers, which are indexes. I want to get a binary number with bits set at those indexes in the list.
For example,

```
my_list=[0,2]
```

I want to get a binary number set at `index 0 and index 2: 101 (or 5 in int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bit-shifting to set specific bits, and the binary or `|` to combine them:

```
>>> bin(1 << 2)
0b100
>>> bin(1 << 0)
0b1
>>> bin(1 << 0 | 1 << 2)
0b101
```

This allows to set bits for every entry in the list:

```
>>> result = 0
>>> for position in my_list:
...    result |= 1 << position 
...
>>> bin(result)
0b101
```

For large numbers, using `reduce` and `map` may be faster:

```
>>> from functools import reduce  # loop-augmented-assignment
>>> from operator import __or__  # the | operator
>>>
>>> #         / result |= ...        / 1 << position 
>>> #         v                      v
>>> reduce(__or__, map(lambda pos: 1 << pos, my_list))
5
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MisterMiyagi.

Comment: Please accept the answer as correct if it solved your problem.